# How do I turn off "when is experimental ..." in perl 5.24?

Tags: perl

The code below was copied directly from the current perlsyn page on perldoc.perl.org.
[I've added an initialization and declarations as needed to make it run (and it works as expected), but the point is the 'when' keyword]

Perl 5.24 complains about 'when' being experimental.
Fair enough, but I don't want to see this every time I use the keyword.

no warnings qw(experimental::when) does not work - "Unknown warning category ..."

I also tried "switch" as the category

Is there another way to suppress this warning (other than disabling warnings in general)?

```
use v5.14;
for ($var) {
    $abc = 1 when /^abc/;
    $def = 1 when /^def/;
    $xyz = 1 when /^xyz/;
    default { $nothing = 1 }
}
```

Comment: The point of the warning is to make you stop using `when`.

Comment: Hardly - it's been around since 5.10.   If "when" shouldn't be used, it certainly would have been removed by 5.26.   The real question is why it still generates an "experimental" warning.

Comment: @grjash smartmatch/when was added in 5.10 as a cute way to port some Perl6 features to Perl5. This didn't work, as the two languages have radically different type systems. The feature was then [retroactively marked experimental in 5.18](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental): *It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. […] Consider, though, replacing the use of these features, as they may change behavior again before becoming stable.*

Comment: `~~`/`given`/`when` is due to get a major overhaul and/or even be **deprecated** as of 5.28. See [smartmatch/switch deprecation for 5.28](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2017/12/msg248507.html) and for a long read [Revisiting smart match](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2017/08/msg245769.html). I would not use any of those three constructs anymore. `if`/`elsif` chains it is...

Comment: @grjash Funny you should mention 5.10. Both `when` and `~~` itself underwent [incompatible changes](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5101delta#Incompatible-Changes) shortly after their introduction. As for "*If "when" shouldn't be used, it certainly would have been removed by 5.26*": Perl doesn't simply remove bad features because that would break older code (or in your case, new code written despite the warnings). You get a deprecation warning first, then a deprecation error, and then maybe it will be removed. This is why e.g. [`reset`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reset.html) is still here.

Answer (score 10):

You can enable this construct without warnings via

```
use experimental 'switch';
```

or merely disable the "experimental" warning category via

```
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

(see the [full list of available warning categories in `perldoc warnings`](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings#Category-Hierarchy)).

But please note that smartmatch, `given`, and `when` constructs are considered to be fundamentally broken, and are being removed/redesigned. Just silencing the warning will break your code when you run that code on other perl versions.

Instead, please prefer out to spell this code out explicitly:

```
for ($var) {
    if    (/^abc/) { $abc = 1 }
    elsif (/^def/) { $def = 1 }
    elsif (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1 }
    else { $nothing = 1 }
}
```

Yes, it's more ugly, but it will also work for all values of `$var` and for all Perl5 versions.

Comment: Mapping warning text to categories can be a little tough.  [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#when-is-experimental) makes the connection much easier to find.

Comment: The official documentation of Perl does not state or even imply that "when" is broken.    It labels "given" as being "highly experimental".
As for the code in the question, it is not accompanied by any warning. - rather, just above on the perlsyn page: "The foreach is the non-experimental way to set a topicalizer."

Comment: @grjash There is pretty strong community consensus that smartmatch (and consequently `when`) in its current form is broken. The `perlsyn` documentation goes in detail about the extremely complex behaviour of this operator. Maintainable code ought to avoid this complexity, as it's likely to be a source of bugs. As the docs say about `when`: *Do not rely upon its current (mis)implementation.*

Comment: `no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => 'experimental::smartmatch';` if you want to support older versions.

Answer (score 3):

`given` and `when` are part of the `smartmatch` experiment, so these warnings can be disabled using:

```
no warnings qw( experimental::smartmatch );
```