# How to remove warnings for "given" and "when" in experimental module

Tags: perl

I am getting op but still i need to clear my warnings. And this is the warning I am getting while executing

> "given is experimental at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/abc.pm"

This is the code I am using
Code:

```
given ($TmpNode->nodeName =~ /^(b|BoldItalic|SmallCaps)$/) {
when ($TmpNode->nodeName =~ /^(b|strong)$/) }
```

Comment: `given/when` are experimental, and as I recall, it is not recommended that you use them at all. Replace them with if/then-logic, and you should be fine.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Switch-Statements

Comment: And also, you are using those statements wrong. It should be `given ($TmpNode->nodeName) { when (/^(b|strong)$/) { do something } }`

Comment: Answer seems to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49328308/725418

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd say stop using `given/when`. It's experimental and at some point someone will have the strong desire to remove it.

But, with v5.18 you can enable a feature and turn off its warnings at the same time:

```
use experimental qw(switch);
```

Prior to v5.18, turn off warnings for that category.

```
no warnings qw(experimental::switch);
```